# WordPress multisite Network Admin redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have redirected my non-www to www in my WordPress multisite using this in `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It works almost perfectly. There's just one issue - Network Admin goes to http://domain.com/wp-admin/network/ (no www) and causes a redirect loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your your permalink settings also have `www` as site and home URL

Comment: Just checked, yep they do.

Comment: hey I had that issue a while ago and the fix suggested here cleared it up.... worth a look in any case http://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/

Comment: Thanks for your response Tom but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is still having this issue, consider adding the following to your wp-config.php:

```
   define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
   define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
   define('COOKIEPATH', '');
   define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

That might help.

Answer (score 0):

There's another possible cause of the loop when trying to access:

```
/wp-admin/network/
```

There's a redirect triggered at the bottom of:

```
/wp-admin/network/admin.php
```

This checks that the current blog and current website have the same path and domain values, if they don't then the redirect occurs.

Double check that the path specified in the **wp_blogs** table is the same as the path set on the current site.

These values can end up out of sync, especially when installing the applications inside a directory, eg. /blog/

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same redirect problem when trying to access wp-admin/network. Performing below changes fixed it.

1). In wp-config file, added www.website.com rather than just website.com
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.website.com');

2). phpmyadmin --> wp_blogs table
Add www. to the domain value

Basically, both site name and blog name have to be exactly the same.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 302 redirect loop error and you cannot access WP-CLI, you can try to disable multisite cache  at web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-site-query.php line 327 with:

$cache_value = false;

After you can remove this line if the site start working